# automatisation of options for select HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an select field in html like

```
<select>
        <option>-</option>
        <option>One</option>
        <option>Two</option>
        <option>Three</option> 
</select>
```

But right now I type in the options manually. But the options should depend on an file I upload.
So ideally I would create an list `list = [One,Two,Three]` (depends on file) and could create my options with that list? Is something like that even possible? Or is the only way of defining those options of an select field by typing them in in advance?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: What do you use to render the HTML?

Comment: You might want to do a little research and make an attempt. Then let us know what you tried and where specifically you got stuck.

Comment: It's certainly possible to have dynamic functionality on a website.  In general what you'd be looking for is just about any server-side language/framework which would read your data and build the web page output based on that data.  Just about any popular language would work, and there are tutorials to get you started with whatever system you choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it using JavaScript. I believe this might help :)

```js
a=["one","two","three"];
a.map((item)=>{               
  var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = item;
    option.text = item;
document.getElementById("root").appendChild(option);  
})
```

```html
<select id="root">
</select>
```

.

Comment: What would be the command for clearing all options before i upload another file or whatever. Because right now the options just add up (the previous are kept). I would like to delete the previous without refreshing the page or load it from the beginning.

Comment: It depends on what type of functionality you want with your webpage/app you can use splice() in some cases as per usecase. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Comment: Appreciate your help but I think you misunderstood me. at least .splice() is not at all what i am looking for (or i dont see it). lets say on an click event i want all options for an select field deleted and replaced by another list. because if i dont delete the previous ones, then new list will just be appended to the existing one (because thats what my code is telling to do...). How do I delete the existing options?

Comment: As per what I understand splice() will definitely work in this use case as it takes 3 parameters the starting index of elements you want to remove the number of elements from that index to be removed and the new elements to be inserted. for deleting existing array you can specify 0 and arr.length as first and second parameters and new elements as third

Comment: The problem is in the code: .appendChild(option). 
I go though every element of the list and append it to the select field. So to splice the list will not do anything, since the elements were already once appended. 
So i am looking for an command to delete or replace already existing options.

Comment: Thanks for your help here. I just found the command i was looking for: 

.removeChild() does it for me

Comment: Your Welcome! BTW I didn't consider  that you wanted a command to remove it from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

In plain javascript, you can loop in javascript using for and in every iteration of your loop you need to use createElement and after that you can use appendChild method of javascript to achieve this.

```
var opt = document.createElement('option'); opt.innerHTML = itr[0]
```